# Checking value type in Java

Tags: java

I need to check whether `4096.0` is same as it's integer form. (In JAVA language)

Is this the correct way?

```
Math.ceil(number) == Math.floor(number);
```

If not, then please suggest the correct way to do this.

Comment: what is the type of `number` ?

Comment: Are you sure you *want* to? See [Is floating point math broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). Floating-point values are often not quite exact, so the value you *think* is 4096.0 could actually be computed as 4096.000000000000000000000000003, due to floating-point arithmetic rules.

Comment: Fun exercise, @sushmita: Run this code: `double x = 0.1 + 0.2; x = x * 10;`. You'll find that, mysteriously, this `x` is __not__ an integer (it is 3.0000000000000004, which is not equal to 3 casted to a double). The general takeaway is that `double` and `float` are datatypes that fundamentally cannot do what you want here. Use something else. For example, if doing finance, represents cents, in a `long`. Or use `BigDecimal` (and read up - that is a very complicated API because asking computers to do this stuff is just intractably difficult).

Comment: `double d=4096.00000;  BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(d);  String s = bd.stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString();    boolean isInteger = s.indexOf(".")==-1;`